# Why show annotation and compare with another revision is not available in Team and Compare With menu for oxygen eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurialeclipse

I have updated Eclipse to latest Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).
Now i can't see option in **Team -> Show Annotation** and also **Compare With -> Another Revision.**

I am using Mercurial plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip ! One should be careful to choose "Show Annotation" rather that "Show Annotations" which also belongs to the Mercurial category but has not the awaited effect.

Comment: As a workaround, "Compare with" can be done in the history tab.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with the mercurial plugin I believe.  I've just upgraded to v2.5.1.201805100452 of the plugin and the contextual menus are back and working.

Answer (score 2):

For a work around if you go to Windows > Preferences > General > Keys and filter using 'Show Annotation' (make sure the category is Mercurial) you can bind a hot key to the command. I'm not sure why its not showing the context menu though.

Comment: I had trouble getting it to work with a keystroke, but I've been able to use it from the Cmd-3 menu.  (It's a frustrating regression!)